# Save a file interactively?

Tags: r, file-io

Using `tk_choose.files` or `file.choose` I am able to select a file interactively. Is there an analogous function wherein I can allow a user to interactively decide where to save the output of a write.table?

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 7 and working through the RGUI, I can specify something like:

```
write.table(x = iris, file = file.choose())
```

which pops open a Windows Explorer dialogue. I can then navigate to any existing file, create a new file by right clicking, or simply by typing the name of a new file where it will ask to create a new file.

I guess this may not be platform independent...can others with the appropriate OS's verify?

Comment: In Linux console version this prompts for a filename; tab-completion works.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
val <- tkgetSaveFile(initialfile="", title="Save a file...")
f <- tclvalue(val)
if(f != "") ...
```

Comment: For those searching - the non-documented but valid arguments are: `confirmoverwrite`, `defaultextension`, `filetypes`, `initialdir`, `initialfile`, `parent`, `title`, `typevariable`

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but after a long search I found that the `tcltk2` package now exists as an improvement of `tcltk`:

```
library(tcltk2)
filename <- tclvalue(tkgetSaveFile())
if (!nchar(filename)) {
  tkmessageBox(message = "No file was selected!")
} else {
  tkmessageBox(message = paste("The file selected was", filename))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Chase - this works in OS X (Eclipse and StatET). At least, I tried writing a data.frame (df) as a CSV file:

```
write.csv(x = df, file = file.choose())
```

Comment: You can't really do much other than overwrite an existing file. Right clicking to choose a new file in this dialog doesn't work on osx.

Comment: With StatET/Eclipse on OS X you get a dialog window in which you can add a name for a new file..