# saving a data file in R

Tags: r, saving-data

I have successfully loaded a .txt file into R. I want to save the data so I can actually actively use it. What is the command for saving a file? Will I save the file to one of the existing packages (UsingR, MASS), or just as a separate file?

Answer (score 15):

The command you look for is either one of these :

- `save()` : saves the mentioned objects as R objects (extension .RData). These files are binary and can be read very quickly again with `load()`
- `write()` : is a wrapper for `cat()` and is used to create text files from objects, usually matrices.
- `write.table()` and `write.csv()` : are commands to write data frames as text files with a specific separator.

Check also `sink()`, used to redirect other output to a file (usually used for logging purposes).

Please read the manuals of R :

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html

Related questions :

- [Save a file interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770515/save-a-file-interactively)
- [Saving a data frame as a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635278/saving-a-data-frame-as-a-binary-file)
- [How do you sink input and output to a text file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983433/how-do-you-sink-input-and-output-to-a-text-file-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to save the data out again - you don't need to save it to use it if you can load from `.txt`? If the loading from the txt file is not prohibitively costly in time (i.e. because it requires lots of processing and reformatting) I don't see the advantage of saving it in a different format. What if someone/you changes the `.txt` files?

Instead, and this is how I tend to work if the data aren't too big/complex, have a data import and processing script that contains the code to load the data, and process it if required, from the `.txt` file. This script is called from my analysis script so that the raw data are loaded, processed and available.

If the data import and processing/formatting is too costly to do each time you want to use the data, then saving out as an R object (via `save()`) as per @Joris Meys' answer.